# Rewrite HTML title tag in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I want to change the title and title head html element. I have tried with `drupal_set_title()` but Drupal insists on adding the site name to the title output. How can I override it so the title reads exactly as I want?

Comment: The question is a little too broad. Where are you exactly using `drupal_set_title()`? Saying you are using it in the template.php file is like using the function in a module. Also, you aren't asking any explicit question, but merely stating facts. Please add an explicit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the page header title in template.php by adding the below code in [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7).

```
 function my_theme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
   if (current_path() == 'you_path') {
     $vars['head_title'] = t('header title');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The title in `drupal_set_title()` only refers to the page title, not the HTML `title` element in `head`. To change that you need to change the `$head_title` variable in [**html.tpl.php**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7)